# Constructor not visible error when importing custom class into Android project

Tags: java, android

I wrote a FileIndexer class in Java, and am attempting to import it into my Android app. However, I get the following error...

```
The constructor FileIndexer(File) is not visible
```

Here is where I attempt to instantiate:

```
import mpss.categorizer.FileIndexer;
...
try {
        FileIndexer indexer = new FileIndexer(getExternalFilesDir(null));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("Indexing", "Error creating FileIndexer: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

And here is the constructor inside FileIndexer:

```
public class FileIndexer {
    private FSDirectory fsDirectory;
    private ArrayList<File> queue;

    public FileIndexer(File f){
        try {
             fsDirectory = FSDirectory.open(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Invalid location: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I created a jar of FileIndexer, and then added it to my Android buildpath. Also, my manifest includes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So it's not that I don't have access to external storage. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: This is a compile time error, right? Are you sure you have imported the correct FileIndexer? What other constructors of FileIndexer are there?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a same class named FileIndexer in your package?

I ran into visibility issue in import once and this was the cause.